# Why does the table embedded in a separate tab panel from the action buttons that modify not correctly render?

Tags: r, shiny, tabs, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

When running the code posted at the bottom, the object "hottable" rendered in the "Slave table" tab does not correctly render when `outputOptions()` is activated at the bottom of the `server()` section of the code, as illustrated in the image below. Comment out `outputOptions()` and "hottable" correctly renders. But the use of `outputOptions()` is critical in this code in order to make "hottable" completely dependent on the column addition/deletion actions in the "Master table" tab (other reactivity problems arise when not using `outputOptions()`). For reasons not shown in this minimalist example, the action buttons have to be a in a separate tab panel from "hottable". How can this be fixed so "hottable" correctly renders without having to click on it?

Illustration:

[image]

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

myDF <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(20,15), check.names = FALSE)
rownames(myDF) <- c('Boy','Girl') 

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(""),sidebarPanel(""),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Master table", hr(),
        actionButton("addSeries", "Add", width = 80),
        fluidRow(
          column(2,actionButton("delSeries","Delete", width = 80)),
          column(3,uiOutput("delSeries1")) 
        ),
      ),
      tabPanel("Slave table", hr(),rHandsontableOutput('hottable'))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  emptyTbl <- reactiveVal(myDF)
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable, {emptyTbl(hot_to_r(input$hottable))})
  
  output$hottable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(emptyTbl(),rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)%>%
      hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = FALSE, allowColEdit = FALSE) %>%
      hot_cols(colWidths = 80)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addSeries, {
    newCol <- data.frame(c(20,15))
    names(newCol) <- paste("Series", ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable)) + 1)
    emptyTbl(cbind(emptyTbl(),newCol))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$delSeries2, {
    tmp <- emptyTbl()                                       
    if(ncol(tmp) > 1){
      delCol <- input$delSeries2                              
      tmp <- tmp[ , !(names(tmp) %in% delCol), drop = FALSE]  
      newNames <- sprintf("Series %d",seq(1:ncol(tmp)))       
      names(tmp) <- newNames                                  
      emptyTbl(tmp)   
    }
  })
  
  output$delSeries1 <- 
    renderUI(
      selectInput("delSeries2", 
                  label = NULL,
                  choices = colnames(hot_to_r(input$hottable)), 
                  selected = "", width = '100px',
                  multiple = TRUE)
      )
  
  outputOptions(output, 'hottable', suspendWhenHidden = FALSE) 
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this bug. Here is the fix:

```r
output$hottable <- renderRHandsontable({
  rhandsontable(emptyTbl(), rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)%>%
    hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = FALSE, allowColEdit = FALSE) %>%
    hot_cols(colWidths = 80) %>%
    htmlwidgets::onRender(
      "function(el, x){
        var hot = this.hot;
        $('a[data-value=\"Slave table\"').on('click', function(){
          setTimeout(function(){ hot.render(); }, 200);
        }); 
      }"
    )
})
```

Not sure the 200 milliseconds in `setTimeout` are necessary.

Comment: Amazing that you remembered this rather obscure bug and even more so that you have a solution. I wish I could give it more than 1 upvote.